# Error when trying to run Node script from Crontab

Tags: node.js, cron

I'm trying to run a very simple Node.js test script (`console.log(2+2);`) from my crontab below:

```
* * * * * /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/node /home/user/testingNode/script.js
```

However I receive the error:

`Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/testingNode/script.js'`

But when I try to run the script outside of cron using Node, it works perfectly fine and outputs `4`:

```
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/node /home/user/testingNode/script.js
```

I installed Node v10.8.0 on my server using nvm and set my node path to point to my global `node_modules` directory, so `echo $NODE_PATH` returns:

```
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules
```

But my guess is that cron is ignoring environment variables set in `.bash_profile` when it runs. I'm not sure what else I could be doing wrong here, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there is a path issue, try doing the following.

```
* * * * * export NODE_PATH=<your global node module dir> && /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/node /home/user/testingNode/script.js
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I also tried `echo $NODE_PATH &&` which should work the same as your answer no?

Comment: should be something like /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

Comment: Yeah in my case its `/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules`, but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Better way to run as really logged in user:

```
0 0-7 * * * /bin/su - root -c "/root/killvnc.sh" 2>&1
```

You get the same exact environment in which you're testing